# Google Maps API V2 google-play-services_lib.jar missing

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I just imported an example of the google map api V2 for android to test. It's missing the `google-play-services_lib.jar`. I can't find this library. Where do I get it?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First check that your sdk contains Google Play Services installed or not.

For that you do the below steps

> In Eclipse--->Window--->Android SDK MAnager--->Check Google Play
>   Services installed in extras.

Then you add the google plays services jar by find that one at the below location

> your-android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs

Comment: Hello, I am having similar problem. It is not installed. i checked in Eclipse, AVD. But when i am trying to install it is showing me error message that nothing to install. Can you please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @RakeshGondaliya Close your eclipse and start SDK Manger manually and try to install it. It may work.

Comment: It is still not working..Showing error. Downloading Google Play services, revision 5
URL not found: C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\temp\google_play_services_3025110_r05.zip (access denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge... It was a stupid mistake.. Actually the message  Access denied was in German , so I didn't understood... Now it worked with Admin login.. Once again thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you do the above and it is still not working because it cant access the temp folder you
can go to your **SDK manager** in your android sdk directory and run it **as an administrator**

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your google-play-services_lib project -> `Build Project`

Right-click on your project using the google-play-services_lib -> `Build Project`