# Importing an existing project to eclipse is giving me a lot of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I imported an existing android project and I just can't get it to work. I'm pretty sure the problem is here [image]

At first, all 3 of those has a red cross at them but I fixed android-support-v4 and google-play-serives, but I just can't find google-play-services_lib anywhere, it's supposed to be in the google-play-services/bin folder, but I don't have that folder, I only have libs folder.

Another problem is also that when I try to open ANYTHING in the project (for example, android manifest or any .java file) it throws me this error.

[image]

Any idea how I could solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all jar files from java build path and follow these steps

```
You should try this:
```

1. Remove all references to the JAR in your project from Java project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries
2. Create a libs folder if not exist at the root of your project Copy the JAR into the libs folder.
3. If still not running OK. Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

clean your project and run. it will work

Comment: I did exactly this and the only thing that's fixed is that I can now open java files and view code. But there are still some red errors next to some files. Any idea how I could figure out why those errors are there?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing google-play-services-lib from your project.If you cant find it then please refer to this question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137511/1238731